# Firebase(Firestore) web app SDK with React JS giving error Missing or insufficient permission

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am not implementing any user specific authentication when fetching data from Firestore as user authentication is being done using SSO. Our ReactJs application is using Firebase Web SDK config to fetch data from Firestore however earlier Firebase SDK used to ignore Firestore security rule but after Firebase V9 SDK it consider Firestore rule as well.

My Question is as follow.

1. By setting `allow read, write if true;` will this rule make our database public and anyone who even doesn't have my Firebase Web SDK Config credentials will be able to access my database?
2. If answer to above question is yes then how I could secure my Firestore database without using Firebase authentication like phone, eamil/password, anonymous i.e. I mean without making any changes in ReactJs application?

Please help me understand Firestore security rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By setting `allow read, write if true;` will this rule make our database
> public and anyone who even doesn't have my Firebase Web SDK Config
> credentials will be able to access my database?

Your database is public with such a rule **but one needs to have your Firebase Project configuration data (Project apiKey)** to read the database content. **However** note that it is not difficult to reverse engineer your front-end code to get this apiKey.

So the answer is Yes.

> If answer to above question is yes then how I could secure my
> Firestore database without using Firebase authentication like phone,
> eamil/password, anonymous i.e. I mean without making any changes in
> ReactJs application?

There isn't any alternative way than using authentication and security rules to protect your database from being read via the Firebase V9 SDK.

You could mimic a 3 tiers architecture approach by using Cloud Functions to interact with Firestore from your front-end (as explained in this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c)) and implement some bespoke secure logic into the Cloud Functions (but using Cloud Functions for reading/writing from/to Firestore has quite some drawbacks and you would need to change your ReactJS app).

Comment: Glad I could help you :-) BTW I'm not sure to understand this sentence from your question: "earlier Firebase SDK used to ignore Firestore security rule but after Firebase V9 SDK it consider Firestore rule as well" => Use of SDKs v8 and lower does not change anything since security rules are implemented in the back end and are enforced whatever method you use to connect to Firestore from a front-end (SDKs or even Firestore REST API) If you experienced some changes at this level it is not because of the SDK version.

Comment: One question, if I will move my firebase query from frontend(ReactJs) to backend(Flask) will that make my firebase database secure with same rule i.e. allow read, write if true;?

Comment: As soon as you use a back-end to interact with the Firestore serverless back-end you can totally close the direct access with a rule like `allow read, write: if false;`. This is because in a back-end you are going to use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) and this SDK totally bypass the security rule (since it is considered being executed from a server you manage). And when using Cloud Functions is exactly the same, this is why I mentioned this possibility in my answer.

Comment: So your back-end (server or Cloud Functions) is a middleware in between your front-end app and the Firestore serverless back-end

Comment: Awesome thanks once again for all the clarifications.